# Cannot install TLS module in powershell

Tags: powershell, ssl, module

I'm trying to install TLS module of Powershell. I can see this module with command:

```
$> Get-Module -ListAvailabe TLS

    Directory: C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                                                                                                        
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                                                                                        
Manifest   2.0.0.0    TLS                                 {New-TlsSessionTicketKey, Enable-TlsSessionTicketKey, Disable-TlsSessionTicketKey, Export-TlsSessionTicketKey}
```

But the installation command failed

```
Install-Module -Name TLS
PackageManagement\Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'TLS'. Try Get-PSRepository to see all available registered module repositories.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\2.0.3\PSModule.psm1:9550 char:21
+ ...          $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

How to install this module?

Comment: is it located in your modules directory?

Comment: does it allow you to `import-module`?

Comment: They are separate cmdlets. Import-Module is a cmdlet to import a module for use. It's in the Powershell Help Files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no module by that name in the MS powershelgllery.com, to install.

```
Find-Module -Name '*tls*'
# Results
<#
Version Name              Repository Description                                                                                                       
------- ----              ---------- -----------                                                                                                       
0.1.0.0 BetterTls         PSGallery  PowerShell Module to Enable TLS 1.1 and 1.2 for Use in Windows PowerShell Where Neither are Enabled by Default    
1.0.0   Test-TlsProtocols PSGallery  Outputs the SSL/TLS protocols that the client is able to successfully use to connect to a server using fqdn or ip.
#>
```

This...

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable TLS
```

... is finding and loading modules, already on your system (in your $env:PSModulePath) for use, is this.

```
Import-Module -Name TLS
```

Or do this

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable TLS | 
Import-Module


Get-Command -Name '*tls*'
# Results
<#
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source                                                                                              
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------                                                                                              
Cmdlet          Disable-TlsCipherSuite                             2.0.0.0    TLS                                                                                                 
Cmdlet          Disable-TlsEccCurve                                2.0.0.0    TLS                                                                                                 
Cmdlet          Disable-TlsSessionTicketKey                        2.0.0.0    TLS                                                                                                 
Cmdlet          Enable-TlsCipherSuite                              2.0.0.0    TLS                                                                                                 
Cmdlet          Enable-TlsEccCurve                                 2.0.0.0    TLS                                                                                                 
Cmdlet          Enable-TlsSessionTicketKey                         2.0.0.0    TLS                                                                                                 
Cmdlet          Export-TlsSessionTicketKey                         2.0.0.0    TLS                                                                                                 
Cmdlet          Get-TlsCipherSuite                                 2.0.0.0    TLS                                                                                                 
Cmdlet          Get-TlsEccCurve                                    2.0.0.0    TLS                                                                                                 
Cmdlet          New-TlsSessionTicketKey                            2.0.0.0    TLS  
#>

# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Get-TlsCipherSuite ).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Get-TlsCipherSuite ).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Get-TlsCipherSuite  -Examples
# Results
<#
Get-TlsCipherSuite
Get-TlsCipherSuite -Name "SSL"
#>
Get-help -Name Get-TlsCipherSuite  -Full
Get-help -Name Get-TlsCipherSuite  -Online
```

Packages are similarly discovered, loaded, and or installed:

```
Find-Package -Name '*tls*'
```

***Update as per your comment about not seeing the cmdlets***
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/tls/?view=win10-ps

WS2K16 Win10 required.

PSVersion for the module/cmdlets:

```
<#
ModuleType Name CmdletName_FinctionName     PowerShellVersion
---------- ---- -----------------------     -----------------
Binary     TLS  Get-TlsEccCurve             5.1              
Binary     TLS  Get-TlsCipherSuite          5.1              
Binary     TLS  Export-TlsSessionTicketKey  5.1              
Binary     TLS  Enable-TlsEccCurve          5.1              
Binary     TLS  Enable-TlsCipherSuite       5.1              
Binary     TLS  Disable-TlsSessionTicketKey 5.1              
Binary     TLS  Disable-TlsEccCurve         5.1              
Binary     TLS  Disable-TlsCipherSuite      5.1              
Binary     TLS  Enable-TlsSessionTicketKey  5.1              
Binary     TLS  New-TlsSessionTicketKey     5.1 
#>
```

***Update based on your comment on the OS version you are running.***

The ***Get-TlsCipherSuite*** is not available on WS2K12 or W2K12R2 as per the MS Docs. Click the version drop-down to see the list.

> WS2K12: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/tls/?view=win10-ps&viewFallbackFrom=winserver2012-ps
>
> W2K12R2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/tls/?view=winserver2012r2-ps

Comment: Why I couldn't get the Cmdlet `Get-TlsCipherSuite` after the import?

Comment: Honestly, I only show the Import because that was the road you were on. By default it is bound to an OS/PS version, thus, there is no need for the Import as all just use the cmdlets as they are there by default. If you ar eon an earlier PS version, then it's not available

Comment: I'm using the same PS version. OS is Windows 2012R2. If I want to get CmdLet Get-TlsCipherSuite, do I need install newer version?

Comment: As for Get-TlsCipherSuite. It's not available on the legacy Windows version, prior to WSW2K16 as per the docs. See my update for you.

Comment: thanks @postanote, that explains everything

Comment: No worries, the OS/PSVersion thing does strip folks up from time to time.